# Use SAP Cloud SDK to integrate with a custom backend service (oData) based on VDM Generator

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

I followed Alexander Duemont's [blog](https://blogs.sap.com/2019/05/06/create-an-application-with-sap-cloud-sdk-to-integrate-with-sap-successfactors/), trying to implement a Java Spring Boot application that consumes Cloud Foundry Destination. The Destination has a custom OData V2 behind it, coming from an On-Premise ERP system. For local dev, when I perform the Maven build, the Integration-Tests module registers failure due to dependency injection

This is part of my Controller

```java
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/resources")
public class ClassificationsController {

    private static final Logger logger =    CloudLoggerFactory.getLogger(ClassificationsController.class);


    private final  ClassificationService service;


    public ClassificationsController(@Nonnull final ClassificationService service) {

        this.service = service;
    }
….. 

}
```

The @Nonnull final ClassificationService Service causes org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException
I cannot use Spring stereotype annotations on generated Service classes (Fluent) to create Beans!

Comment: Hi SHK! I'm not exactly sure what you expect to happen and what happens instead. The generated service classes do not have any annotation, as far as I'm aware, so if you want Spring to automatically inject them somewhere (e.g. your ClassificationsController), then you will have to take care of that yourself. Alternatively, if you don't want to Spring to do anything but it currently tries to do stuff, then I'd probably also check your configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is more likely related to Spring Boot configuration.

I'm assuming `ClassificationService` is an interface and the implementing class exists in the same package.

Please make sure...

- ... to add the implementing class of `ClassificationService` to your component scan / test runtime. Feel free to share the integration test code to setup the test environment. Maybe the additional class reference is missing.
- ... to correctly annotate the respective *Application* class of your Spring Boot project. For example, assuming your `ClassificationService` resides in `org.example.services.classification`, while the rest of your application uses `org.example.app`. Your basic *Application* class would look like this, when following the *Cloud SDK* guide:

  ```java
  @SpringBootApplication
  @ComponentScan({"com.sap.cloud.sdk", "org.example.services.classification", "org.example.app"})
  @ServletComponentScan({"com.sap.cloud.sdk", "org.example.app"})
  public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer
  {
      @Override
      protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure( final SpringApplicationBuilder application )
      {
          return application.sources(Application.class);
      }

      public static void main( final String[] args )
      {
          SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
      }
  }
  ```
- ... to annotate the implementing class of `ClassificationService` with `javax.inject.Named`. In case you have multiple implementations of the same interface, make sure to give the not-used class a custom (unique) value for the `@Named` annotation.
- ... to look for exceptions (*Class not found*) in the application log during startup.

Comment: Thanks @Alexander. I'd not registered the Service class in the component Scans! One question: is there a GIT to this blog? Also, how do I debug my code locally?